# Where can find a comprehensive list of all the Computer Science courses in California on CBEDS?

Tags: data-request, education

I'm looking for a comprehensive list of all the Computer Science courses in CA on [CBEDS](http://www.cde.ca.gov/ds/dc/cb/) with the following course codes:

- 2451  Computer Programming
- 2453  Computer Science
- 2465  IB Computer Science
- 2470  AP Computer Science A
- 2471  AP Computer Science AB
- 4619  Computer Programming for Solving Applied Problems
- 4634  Exploring Computer Science

And maybe:

- 2454  Computer lab
- 2455  Web design
- 2458  Other Computer Education